# Correcting and explaining corrections without sounding superior

Tags: moderators, editing

So, I am a moderator on a forum dedicated to scientific exploration, the specifics of which I will not get in to.

The main point of this forum is to correct other's incorrect assumptions and ideas about this particular science.

However, when I make changes to someone's post and explain why, I inevitably start sounding like a douchebag.  Such as, '*blank* is incorrect, here's why:'.  This sounds very harsh.

How do I phrase changes to make them sound less rude?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Sentences like this sound less harsh:

> Hi, I edited your post because *blank* is actually not correct, because *[enter reason here]*.

This is less harsh because:

- You use a greeting.
- You state that you edited the post. It might be that the user has not yet noticed that (and only noticed your comment), so I think it is a good idea to explicitly state that.
- "actually not correct" looks kinder than "incorrect". Or, as Nick Wilde mentioned, "not quite correct" is also nice here.
- "because" looks kinder than "here's why"

Comment: Depending on degree of incorrectness I also like 'not quite correct'